# Storing DateTime in Arraylist in java swt

Tags: java, datetime, swt

I'm having some problem with my program. I'm trying to get the values of the date from the `dateTime` widget from the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime`. My program is working, when i change the date it will store in the `Arraylist` and print it. But my problem is I don't know if it's saving or not and how can i get the values of all the date that are stored in the Arraylist?

so far this is what I tried

```
public void readDateList()
{
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateFrom.getDay());
    instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateFrom.getMonth());
    instance.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateFrom.getYear());
    String strDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(instance.getTime());

    ArrayList<String> alDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    alDate.add(strDateString);
    System.out.println(alDate);     
}
```

Comment: **Hint:** every time you call ***readDateList***, the old object ***alDate*** is gone for good and you are creating a NEW one!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ so how can I do that? I mean i should change like these `ArrayList<String> readDateList(String)`? Sorry Im confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that
every time you call `readDateList()`, the old object `alDate` is gone for good and you are creating a *new* one.

Remove `alDate` from the method `readDateList` and make it global to the class.

```
ArrayList<String> alDate = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add a new method to print the list, like:

```
public void printList(){
    System.out.println(alDate);     
}
```

Comment: @abrakadabrahastags "make it global to the class" means declare it as class field. Declaring it inside the method means it is only visible inside that block (in this case method). When it goes out of scope (method ends) it will not be accessible any more and the GC will collect it sooner or later. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: @Fildor gotcha thanks man! I'm too slow with understanding this. and also to you Xoce